# Is *.dat file suitable for storing high (>2) dimensional matrix?

Tags: export, import, data, data-structures

The typical process goes as first one exports a numerical matrix `mat`

```
Export["test.dat",mat,"Table"]
```

and then imports it back by using

```
Import["test.dat","Table"]
```

This is necessary, especially when the evaluation of `mat` is relatively time-consuming and the value of `mat` is expected to be used many times.

When `mat` is a 1-dimensional vector or 2-d matrix, one gets what s/he wants (what is imported is what exactly has been exported). However, to one's surprise, the procedure fails when `mat` is a 3-d matrix (of Depth 4) --- what imported becomes many strings.

It has been found that `*.mat` file may do the job. But, is there any way to make `*.dat` to do the job as well?

Comment: worth a note, the "dat" extension has no bearing on what you did there (or any of the answers here).  The last argument to `Import`/`Export` is a directive to ignore the extension.   (the dat extension is so generic it is meaningless anyway)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Put` and `Get`.

Having

```
l1 = {{a1, {a, b, c, d, e}}, {a2, {f, g, h, i}}}
```

one exports using

```
Put[l1,"out.dat"]
```

and imports next with

```
Get["out.dat"]
```

This works for arbitrary depth lists.

Comment: @Feyre: where do you see temp files here?

Comment: @AlbertRetey I misread the documentation. I was surprised `Put[]` works so much faster. I don't think `Export[]` is better than `Put[]` in this case, in fact `Put[]` seems to be faster. I have concordantly upvoted this answer.

Comment: Marvelous  & remarkable!

Comment: Another question. Can we set where to put things?

Comment: @Alexander, look at `SetDirectory[]`.

Answer (score 5):

```
dat = RandomReal[10, {3, 3, 3}];
Export["test.dat", dat, "List"];
dat2 = ToExpression[Import["test.dat", "List"]];
Simplify[dat == dat2]
```

> `True`

```
dat // MatrixForm
dat2 // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that "ToExpression" is indispensable?

Comment: @AlexanderZeng Unless you want to work with temp files, yes.

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is better than just using `Put` and `Get`?

Answer (score 4):

If you just need to store an expression to file to later reload it to Mathematica the by far most efficient way is this:

```
Export["mat.mx",mat]
mat = Import["mat.mx"]
```

it will work for every Mathematica expression containing whatever you want and that of course includes arrays of arbitrary depth. The drawback is of course that these files can only be reloaded with Mathematica and no other program. And AFAIK there is no guarantee that they are compatible between different (major) Mathematica versions.

(note that for some newer data structs like graphs, datasets, neural networks, mesh regions... there might be bugs for some versions, so you better check whether what you want to safe can be reloaded, but the same is true for any other file format of course)

Answer (score 2):

I have been using

```
Export["file.txt", Compress[whatever]]
Uncompress[Import["file.txt"]]
```